# Regex to allow number greater than 0.5

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i'm working on some regex now and i want to add the conditional to allow only numbers greater than 0.5 here is my regex

```
^(?![.0]*$)[0-9]+(?:\.[1-9]{1,2})?$
```

i just want to values between 0 and 0.5 don't match this.
Thanks

Comment: why wouldn't you just convert to number and compare that way?

Comment: ?? Why on earth wouldn't you just convert the string to a number and do a numeric comparison??

Comment: Because i need a regex thats the way you can learn something i know i can make a numeric comparison i asked for a regex

Answer (score 8):

Regular expressions are awesome, but they can get hard to read and maintain.  This feels like a scenario where you should just parse the string and compare the value.

```
var num = parseFloat(input);
if (num > 0.5)
    ...
```

Comment: Just to play devils advocate on this, consider `.50000000001` [is it really greater than .5?](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=.50000000001+%3E+.5)

Comment: Thanks but i need the regex ;) that is the reason i asked

Answer (score 1):

```
(^(?![.0]*$)[1-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$)|(^(?![.0]*$)[0]+(?:\.[5-9][0-9]*)?$)
```

and its easy to read too!

Comment: Thanks but i think something it's missing does not allow zeros after the first digit

Comment: @user2720108 weird, i'll check it out

Comment: what is the range of numbers ur looking to validate? any decimal number, numbers between 0 and 10, something else?

Comment: all numbers greater or equal to 0.5 with two decimals only no leading zeros no negatives and also 0.50

Comment: no I mean what range are you trying to validate, I know you want to only allow greater than 0.5 but what is the allowed input

Comment: got it ^([0-9]+|[0-9]+[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}+|[1-9]\.[0-9]+|0\.[5-9][0-9]?)$

Answer (score 0):

This regexp may works: ([Check here](https://regex101.com/r/mU7yA4/1))

```
^([0-9]+|[0-9]+[0-9]\.[0-9]+|[1-9]\.[0-9]+|0\.[5-9][0-9]*)$
```

Comment: thanks this was really helpful i got this ^([0-9]+|[0-9]+[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}+|[1-9]\.[0-9]+|0\.[5-9][0-9]?)$

Comment: It matches `0` and `0.5` but not `0.51`

Comment: It still matches `0`  and  `0.5` and  `000.000`

Answer (score 0):

This regex works allows two decimals and numbers greater than 0.50

```
^((?!0*(\.0+)?$)[0-9]+|[0-9]+[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,2}+|[1-9]\.[0-9]+|0\.[5-9][0-9]?)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should use @dontangg 's answer.

But if you want a regex, here is one that do the job:

```
^(?:0\.5[1-9]\d*|0\.[6-9]\d*|\d+[1-9](?:\.\d+)?)$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : begining of string
    (?:             : begining of non-capture group
        0\.5[1-9]\d*:  0. followed by number greater than 50
        |           :
        0\.[6-9]\d* : 0. followed by number greater than 5 then any number of digits
        |           : OR
        \d+[1-9]    : any digit followed by number from 1 to 9
        (?:         : begining of non-capture group
            \.\d+   : a dot followed by any digits
        )?          : end of non capture group, optional
    )               : end of non-capture group
$                   : end of string
```

It matches:

```
0.51
12
12.34
```

It doesn't match:

```
0
0.2
0.25
0.5
0.50
```